# JS: I have a function that activates twice instead of once?

Tags: javascript

I have a video game where a player can select up to 3 skills when he chooses to upgrade them. So imagine its time for you to upgrade 1 of your skills, a radial selector pops up, giving you the option to choose 3 different skills.

[image]

The function I have below works if the user clicks 1 time on any skill. However during the testing phase, I clicked the "upgrade me" button to activate it, then I selected "strike" and then "defend" (or multiple skills). Then I clicked the first skill on the radial selector. Instead of that 1 skill getting upgraded, it upgraded BOTH skills.

Strike gets replaced with Deepcut

Defend gets replaced with StoneWall

Only ONE skill should of been upgraded, NOT both.

When I reviewed my function below, I cannot figure out why both buttons update at the same time after multiple clicks. I am assuming it was adding the list together, but when I did console.log(list), it only referenced the skills I coded in the switch statement.

```
function radialSelector(object){
    var list;
     switch (object){
        case strike:
        list = [deepcut, balancedstrike, fury];
        break;
        case defend:
        list = [stonewall, digin, holdtheline];
        break;
        default:
        console.log("radialSelector() has set its switch statement to default")
    }

    console.log(object);
    console.log(list);
    for (var i=0, l=list.length; i<l; i++) {
    radialSubMenuSkills("position"+(i+1), list[i]);
    }


    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').on('click', '#position1', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(list[0]);
        removeRadialSubMenu();
    });
}
```

Extra Code

```
 function removeSkillButton(object) {
     var x = dom.el(object.name);
     x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
    }

 function addSkillButton(object) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        var target = dom.el("skillListWrapper");
        button.textContent = object.name;
        button.setAttribute("id", object.name);
        button.setAttribute("class", "selection");

    switch(object.category){
        case "Attack": 
        target.insertBefore(button, target.children[0]);
        break;
        case "Defend": 
        target.insertBefore(button, target.children[1]);
        break;
        case "Healing": 
        target.insertBefore(button, target.children[2]);
        break;
        case "Debuff": 
        target.insertBefore(button, target.children[3]);
        break;
        default:
        console.log("addSkillButton() - Case Statement has switched to default");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a fiddle? Thx

Comment: I would, but the code snippet feature seems to be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason both skills get upgraded, is that whenever you click to select a skill, you attach a click handler to `#upgradeSkillsBar`. These accumulate, i.e. the assignment of the handler does not replace the previously assigned handler, but adds a new one to the list of handlers to execute on the click event.

To avoid this accumulation, call [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) before `.on()`, like this:

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').off('click').on('click', '#position1', function(){
    //... etc
```

Comment: Just 2 minutes ago, I figured out that my clicks were getting added. Ex: Deep Cut would be added 10 times if I clicked Strike 10 times. Then I come back here and you post this. Thank you so much, this explains everything! I just wish it wasn't set to default to accumulative. That would of saved me 3 hours.